# Use slurm job id

Tags: linux, batch-processing, hpc, slurm

When I launch a computation on the cluster, I usually have a separate program doing the post-processing at the end :

```
sbatch simulation
sbatch --dependency=afterok:JOBIDHERE postprocessing
```

I want to avoid mistyping and automatically have the good job id inserted. Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
RES=$(sbatch simulation) && sbatch --dependency=afterok:${RES##* } postprocessing
```

The `RES` variable will hold the result of the `sbatch` command, something like `Submitted batch job 102045`. The construct `${RES##* }` isolates the last word (see more info [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)), in the current case the job id. The `&&` part ensures you do not try to submit the second job in the case the first submission fails.

Comment: Note that in recent versions of Slurm, `sbatch` has a `--parsable` parameter so that only the jobid is returned, simplifying this as `RES=$(sbatch --parsable simulation)`

Comment: Beware that on a federated cluster,  `sbatch` will give the name of the cluster in addition to the job id.

Comment: Note, using `--parsable` flag you might get a comma separated list. From the man page of `sbatch`: `--parsable` Outputs only the job id number and the cluster name if present.  The values are separated by a semicolon. Errors will still be displayed.

Comment: Another method would be to include in your script something like echo $SLURM_JOB_ID this will echo the exported env variable