# Save slurm job ID as you submit the job with sbatch

Tags: shell, slurm

Is there a way to submit a job to slurm with sbatch as record the job id into a variable?

```
job_id = sbatch --account my_account some_script.sh

echo $job_id

17210254
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960332/use-slurm-job-id

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done with `--parsable`

```
job_id=$(sbatch --parsable test.sh)
echo $job_id
17211434
```