# SLURM get job id of last run jobs

Tags: slurm

Is there a way to get the last *x* SLURM job ids of (finished) jobs for a certain user (me)?

Or maybe all job IDs run the *x*-hours?

(My use case is, that I want to get some metrics via a `sacct`but idealy don't want to parse them from outputfiles etc.)

For the next time it's maybe adviseable to plan this in advance, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64048945/save-slurm-job-id-as-you-submit-the-job-with-sbatch)…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To strictly answer the question, you can use `sacct` like this:

```
sacct -X --start now-3hours -o jobid
```

This will list the jobs of the jobs that started within the past 3 hours.

But then, if what you want is to feed those job IDs to `sacct` to get metrics, you can directly add the metrics to the `-o` option, or remove that `-o` option altogether.

Also, the `-X` is there to have one line per job, but memory-related metrics are stored per job step, so you might want to remove it at some point to get one line per job step instead..

Comment: If you only want the single most recent job ID, just append `| tail -n 1` to the above command.